# Hibernate relacion muchos a muchos con ID compuesta genera siguiente valor de la secuencia en la tabla de relación

Tags: oracle, hibernate

Utilizo hibernate 3.2 para administrar usuarios con oracle. Debido a que la relación en la tabla roles_de_usuario tiene un campo extra de fecha de asignación del rol, se generó una clase que maneja ese campo extra (UserRoleId). El id en la tabla de usuarios se maneja con secuencias. El problema es que al insertar se genera un valor para la tabla de relación "roles_de_usuario" y el siguiente valor de la secuencia(+1) para la tabla "usuarios" por lo tanto provoca error debido a la violación de la restricción de claves foráneas.

java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-02291: restricción de integridad () violada - clave principal no encontrada

Deshabilitando la restricción se observa que el problema es que genera un valor para la relación y el siguiente valor para la tabla usuarios.

diagrama
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Datos insertados
[image: Datos]

Clase Embeddable para ID compuesta

```
@Embeddable
public class UserRoleId implements java.io.Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Role role;
    
    //aqui hay un bloque de constructores, setters y getters

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (this == object) 
            return true;
        if (object == null || getClass() != object.getClass()) 
            return false;

        UserRoleId that = (UserRoleId) object;

        if (user != null ? !user.equals(that.user) : that.user != null) 
            return false;
        if (role != null ? !role.equals(that.role) : that.role != null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result;
        result = (user != null ? user.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (role != null ? role.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Clase de relación entre usuarios y roles, usando el ID compuesto definido anteriormente

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles_de_usuario", schema =  Configurations.SCHEMA_ENT)
@AssociationOverrides({ @AssociationOverride(name = "userRoleId.user", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario")),
                        @AssociationOverride(name = "userRoleId.role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_rol"))
    })
public class UserRole implements Serializable{

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserRoleId userRoleId = new UserRoleId();
    @Column(name = "fecha")
    private Date date;

    public UserRole() {
        super();
    }

    public UserRole(UserRoleId userRoleId, Date date) {
        this.userRoleId = userRoleId;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setUserRoleId(UserRoleId userRoleId) {
        this.userRoleId = userRoleId;
    }

    public UserRoleId getUserRoleId() {
        return userRoleId;
    }
    
   
    public void setUser(User user) {
        getUserRoleId().setUser(user);
    }
    @Transient //no persistente
    public User getUser() {
        return getUserRoleId().getUser();
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        getUserRoleId().setRole(role);
    }
    @Transient
    public Role getRole() {
        return getUserRoleId().getRole();
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        UserRole that = (UserRole) o;
        if (getUserRoleId() != null ? !getUserRoleId().equals(that.getUserRoleId())
            : that.getUserRoleId() != null)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return (getUserRoleId() != null ? getUserRoleId().hashCode() : 0);
    }
```

Clase usuarios

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuarios", schema =  Configurations.SCHEMA_ENT)
public class User implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "usuarios_idusuario_au")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="usuarios_idusuario_au", sequenceName = "usuarios_idusuario_au",allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id_usuario", unique = true, nullable = false)
    long userId;
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    String name;
    @Column(name = "apellidos")
    String lastName;
    @Column(name = "usuario")
    String user;
    @Column(name = "password")
    String password;
    @Column(name = "fecha_creacion")
    Date creationDate;
    @Column(name = "fecha_acceso")
    Date accessDate;
    @Column(name = "correo")
    String email;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userRoleId.user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>();

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public User(long userId, String name, String lastName, String user, String password, Date creationDate,
                Date accessDate, String email) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
        this.accessDate = accessDate;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public User(long userId, String name, String lastName, String user, String password, Date creationDate,
                Date accessDate, String email, Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
        this.accessDate = accessDate;
        this.email = email;
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }

    //Aqui van un bloque de setters y getters autogenerados

    
    public void addUserRole(UserRole userRole) {
        this.userRoles.add(userRole);
    }
    
}
```

Clase roles

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles", schema =  Configurations.SCHEMA_ENT)
public class Role implements Serializable{
    @Id //Indica clave primaria
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) //Autoincremantable
    @Column(name = "id_rol", unique = true, nullable = false) //nombre de la columna
    private long roleId;
    @Column(name = "rol")
    private String role;
    @Column(name = "descripcion")
    private String description;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }) //Relación owning side con permisos
    @JoinTable(name = "permisos_por_rol", 
               joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_rol") },
               inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "permiso")}
               )
    private Set<Role> roles; 
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userRoleId.role")
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>();
    
    public Role() {
        super();
    }
    //aqui hay construcctores
    
    public void addUserRole(UserRole userRole){
        this.userRoles.add(userRole);
    }
    //Bloque de setter  getter
}
```

Y finalmente la clase que hace la inserción

```
for(String strRole: strRoles){
                Role role = new Role();
                UserRole userRole = new UserRole();
                role = roleDao.get(Long.parseLong(strRole));
                userRole.setUser(user);
                userRole.setRole(role);
                userRole.setDate(Util.getCurrentDate("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
                user.addUserRole(userRole);
            }
           
            userService.save(user);
```

El método save llama al método save genérico de hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Tu base de datos esta mal diseñada, una muy mala practica de programación es usar llaves compuestas y peor es usarla en una relación muchos a muchos. **Para esa tabla donde tienes la llave compuesta crea un `unique` con los campos de la llave compuesta, elimina la llave compuesta y crea una llave con un `id` entero o long que se autoincremente solo para esa tabla. Eso es solo en diseño de la bd, una vez haciendo eso veraz como tus problemas se empiezan a resolver en `hibernate`**.

¿Por son una mala practica las llaves compuestas?
Respuesta: [Cómo elegir la clave primaria de una tabla](https://inmensia.com/blog/20070223/elegir_clave_primaria_tabla_base_datos_oracle.html)

Cito:

> A veces tengo la impresión de que elegir las columnas que constituirán
> la clave primaria de una tabla es una decisión que suele tomarse muy a
> la ligera, cuando la realidad es que la correcta elección de las
> claves primarias es un factor decisivo para poder construir un modelo
> relacional de base de datos bien formado, coherente, mantenible y
> fácilmente ampliable. Lo más irónico del asunto es que en realidad
> resulta una tarea muy sencilla si se comprende que ningún valor tomado
> del dominio que estamos intentando modelar sirve para identificar
> unívocamente a los registros en base de datos. Dicho de otra forma, no
> puede utilizarse como clave primaria una columna que contenga
> información que tenga significado para los usuarios; hay que crear una
> columna expresamente para la clave primaria. O dicho de una tercera
> forma, si tiene que crear una tabla de personas no utilice DNI como
> clave primaria.
>
> ¿Pero por qué no es una buena idea elegir DNI como clave primaria?,
> ¿acaso ese número no nos identifica de forma unívoca?. Pues sí, pero
> rotundamente NO. Piense por ejemplo que los menores de edad o los
> ciudadanos de otros paises no tienen normalmente un carnet de
> identidad, y todo ello sin mencionar además el hecho de que los
> números del DNI no son únicos, históricamente la misma numeración se
> ha reutilizado en distintas personas.
>
> Puede que en este momento esté pensando en alternativas muy
> inteligentes para tratar de resolver los problemas que se plantean en
> el párrafo anterior, posiblemente mediante la incorporación de nuevas
> columnas a la clave primaria, pero créame, déjelo, el esfuerzo será
> inútil, la realidad es que los problemas no desaparecerán, se
> incrementarán. Por ejemplo, podemos pensar que podremos almacenar
> menores de edad en nuestra tabla si añadimos una nueva columna a la
> clave primaria que nos indique si en realidad el DNI es suyo o de su
> representante legal. Pero ocurre que una persona puede tener varios
> hijos, con lo cual necesitariamos otra nueva columna para
> distinguirlos. También podemos pensar que podremos almacenar personas
> de distintos paises si añadimos una nueva columna que nos indique la
> nacionalidad de cada persona, permitiendo así además que un mismo
> número se repita para personas de distintos paises. Pero ocurre que
> una persona puede tener varias nacionalidades. Y así, vuelta a
> empezar. Lo normal es que siguiendo esta línea de razonamiento se
> acabe necesitando facilmente 7 u 8 columnas más. En lineas generales
> no se deben utilizar claves primarias compuestas en las tablas
> maestras, es decir, claves formadas por varias columnas en las tablas
> que almacenan las entidades básicas que gestiona un sistema. Complica
> los modelos haciéndolos difíciles de mantener y ampliar. Piense en el
> ejemplo anterior, en si persitieramos en nuestra idea original de
> utilizar DNI como clave primaria, de forma que el día de mañana nos
> encontráramos un problema de los antes citados, y que además lo
> solucionáramos añadiendo un nuevo campo a la clave primaria. Pues
> ocurriría que tendriamos que añadir ese nuevo campo a todas las tablas
> y procesos que hicieran referencia a la tabla de personas. El cambio
> no sería único y localizado, si no que se expandería como una
> enfermedad contagiosa por todas las entidades y procesos del sistema
> que tuvieran algún tipo de relación con la tabla de personas.
>
> Hay que tener cuidado con las claves compuestas, sobre todo porque a
> veces se presentan camufladas bajo la apariencia de lo que normalmente
> se denominan «códigos inteligentes». Un código inteligente es la unión
> de varias claves en una sola columna, o sea, una clave primaria
> compuesta con piel de cordero. Un ejemplo típico de este tipo de
> código son los localizadores, como el de una entrada de cine en la que
> figura «S07-F12-B08», lo que vendría a significar «Sala 7» (S07) «Fila
> 12» (F12) «Butaca 8» (B08). Este tipo de composición se utiliza a
> veces para identificar las entidades por su ubicación, suponiendo el
> hecho de que sólo puede haber una entidad en un mismo sitio a un mismo
> tiempo. El principal problema que plantea este tipo de clave primaria
> es que a veces, en el mundo real, las entidades se extravían y acaban
> en localizaciones distintas a las que indican sus códigos, siendo
> necesario cambiar las claves primarias en la tabla principal y en
> todas las tablas en las que aparezcan referenciadas, lo que puede ser
> bastante laborioso, por no decir engorroso y proclive a errores.
>
> El párrafo anterior nos da las dos últimas pistas definitivas para
> entender el por qué no hay que utilizar DNI como clave primaria de la
> tabla de personas. La primera pista es que una clave primaria nunca
> puede depender de información introducida manualmente. Si se hace
> depender el valor de una clave primaria de lo que escriba un usuario
> se está creando una dependencia brutal de éste con el funcionamiento
> interno del sistema. El acoplamiento entre capas de una aplicación
> siempre debe ser débil, de forma que se pueda modificar cada
> componente de forma individual sin afectar al resto, y en
> consecuencia, las reglas que rigen el mundo real no tienen porque
> influir en las que se establecen en el interior de una aplicación. Si
> la clave primaria de la tabla persona fuera DNI, y el día de mañana se
> decidiera utilizar el NIF, entonces se tendría que cambiar todo el
> modelo y los procesos para gestionar la clave como un campo
> alfanumérico en vez de como sólo nunérico. Si DNI no fuera clave
> entonces bastaría con cambiar ese campo concreto de forma aislada.
>
> La segunda pista es que una clave primaria nunca ha de poder
> modificarse. La clave primaria de un registro identifica de forma
> unívoca a un objeto dentro del dominio que se está modelando. Si se
> cambia la clave primaria de un registro se produce una «mutación» por
> la cual el registro pasa a representar a otro objeto. Este aspecto
> quizás sea un poco sutil de entender, sobre todo por que conlleva
> cierto nivel de abstracción. Una persona se podría decir que es la
> suma de sus características individuales, así como del lugar que ocupa
> en cualquiera de las dimensiones en las que se proyecta (y
> posiblemente de su ausencia en las dimensiones en las que no se
> proyecta). Es una entidad, un ser único y distinguible. Su clave
> primaria ha de identificarlo de forma unívoca, si se cambia
> representaría otra entidad, no al individuo original. Piense en
> términos de variables, como las que se utilizan normalmente en
> cualquier lenguaje de programación. Primero se definen, y luego se les
> puede cambiar su contenido, de igual forma que una persona puede
> cambiarse de ropa o de peinado. Las variables siempren hacen
> referencia a una misma información concreta, independientemente del
> valor que contengan en un momento dado. Con las personas ocurre lo
> mismo, da igual el peinado o la ropa que llevemos, e incluso donde nos
> encontremos, por encima de todo seguimos siendo nosotros mismos, no
> otros. Si a una persona se le cambia su DNI porque se introdujo un
> número equivocado en el alta, debe seguir siendo la misma entidad que
> se insertó originalmente en el sistema, no otra distinta que implique
> una actualización masiva de las relaciones.
>
> En definitiva, la forma correcta de identificar las entidades en una
> tabla es utilizar un código o identificador único que carezca de
> significado en el mundo real. Un simple valor numérico generado de
> forma secuencial es suficiente. La idea es crear una tabla con una
> primera columna de tipo numérico que sirva como clave primaria. En el
> ejemplo inicial, la tabla de personas, podría ser algo como: ID_PERSON
> NUMBER(10) NOT NULL. De forma que cuando se inserte una primera
> persona en la tabla se le asigne el valor 1 como clave primaria (ó
> 1527, es indistinto). Cuando se inserte una nueva persona se le asigne
> el 2 (ó 1528). Y así sucesivamente. De esta forma no hay posibilidad
> de conflictos, o lo que es lo mismo, de encontrarse con errores por
> claves primarias duplicadas. Cada persona queda emparejada con un
> identificador que le distingue unívocamente del resto. Y lo dicho para
> persona sirve para cualquier tipo de entidad. Un motor no se
> identifica por su número de bastidor, sino por su clave primaria. Un
> televisor no se identifica por su número de serie, sino por su clave
> primaria. Una factura no se identifica por su número, sino por su
> clave primaria. Un usuario no indentifica por su nombre, sino por
> clave primaria. ¿Captan la idea?
>
> Esta forma de definir las claves suele crear bastante confusión en los
> desarrolladores no acostumbrados a esta forma de modelar. Las primeras
> cuestiones que se suelen plantear son la tocantes al rendimiento,
> sobre todo porque las búsquedas por columnas como DNI son bastantes
> habituales. Al dejar de ser parte de la clave primaria hay que definir
> índices adicionales sobre las tablas para estas columnas. Algunos
> diseñadores reniegan espontáneamente cuando se sugiere añadir varios
> índices sobre una misma tabla alegando que corresponde a un mal
> diseño. Pero entonces, ¿para qué diablos queremos los índices?. Otra
> cuestión habitual que se suele plantear es cómo generar las claves
> primarias. La respuesta creo que depende en gran medida de las
> herramientas que se utilicen para desarrollar. Oracle por ejemplo
> proporciona los objetos de tipo SEQUENCE, que generan valores
> secuenciales de forma atómica. Algunos gestores permiten indicar que
> las columnas sean autoincrementales, de forma que cada vez que se
> inserta un registro se genera automáticamente un nuevo valor. Los
> «gurús» suelen divagar acerca de aspectos tales como si es necesario
> utilizar una única secuencia para todas las entidades del sistema o
> una secuencia distinta para cada tabla. Lo que está claro es que nunca
> se debe ejecutar COUNT o MAX sobre las tablas para obtener el
> siguiente secuencial, son atentados directos contra la integridad y el
> rendimiento de la aplicación. Otra cuestión que se suele plantear es
> el tema del tamaño requerido por la columna de la clave primaria. Un
> tamaño de 10 representa una cantidad de diez billones de valores
> posibles, suficiente para la mayoría de aplicaciones de propósito
> general. Lo que hay que hacer sobre todo es que todas las tablas
> tengan una columna de clave primaria con el mismo tamaño, no cada una
> con un tamaño distinto ajustado en función de su ocupación estimada.
> Referente a esta última cuestión, hay que matizar que añadir una
> columna de tamaño diez no implica añadir automáticamente 10 bytes por
> registro, el espacio adicional requerido dependerá enteramente del
> gestor de base de datos que se esté utilizando.
>
> Trabajar con tablas definidas de esta forma por primera vez puede
> resultar un tanto inquietante al principio. Puede parecer que mantener
> la coherencia de tantos identificadores es algo complicado, pero no lo
> es, de hecho, hoy en día es la forma más natural de diseñar y
> trabajar. Simplifica el diseño de las capas de persistencia con las
> que se consiguen mapear los objetos en memoria, al tiempo que ayuda a
> separar la información que resulta significativa para los usuarios de
> la forma en que se gestiona internamente. Si sus herramientas no
> soportan esta forma de trabajar vaya pensando seriamente en
> sustituirlas por otras nuevas.
>
> Y por último, no quería dejar de comentar el hecho de que seguramente
> todos estos razonamientos parezcan complicaciones innecesarias para
> sistemas pequeños en ambientes muy controlados. Sin embargo, pensar
> así es olvidar una máxima informática que hay que tener siempre muy
> presente: ¡los requerimientos siempren cambian!